# jenkins pipeline - use perform maven release button

Tags: maven, jenkins, release, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any option how to add "perform maven release" button into jenkins pipeline job. I am using option with another stage in pipeline which wait 2 minutes for user input but I don't like that every time job job waits and release is only sometimes.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwFF6.jpg

Comment: What step do you want to add and where?

Comment: When I'm configuring maven project, I can configure maven release options and after that I have maven release button on the left panel of job. But when I am using pipeline project I can't do this. So I want this button in pipeline project. Is it possible? Thanks for your answer. PS. I added the screen of maven project left panel to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've he same issue... No, The M2 Release plugin only works with Maven projects, not freestyle or Pipeline, but you can use user input from pipeline to achieve the same result:

```
stage('release')
    {       
        def performRelease = input  message             : "Perform Maven Release?", 
                                    ok                  : "Schedule Maven Release Build", 
                                    submitter           : env.ALLOWED_SUBMITTER_RELEASE, 
                                    submitterParameter  : 'APPROVING_SUBMITTER',
                                    parameters: 
                                    [   
                                        booleanParam
                                        (
                                            defaultValue: true, 
                                            description: '',
                                            name: 'Dry run only?'
                                        ),                              
                                        string
                                        (
                                            defaultValue: '', 
                                            description: '', 
                                            name: 'Release Version'
                                        ), 
                                        string
                                        (
                                            defaultValue: '', 
                                            description: '', 
                                            name: 'Development version'
                                        )                                       
                                    ]

        if( performRelease )
        {
            dir( env.PROJECT_FOLDER ) 
            {
                withMaven(jdk:  env.JDK_VERSION , maven:  env.MVN_VERSION )
                {
                    sh "mvn ${ performRelease['Dry run only?'] ? env.MVN_RELEASE_DRYRUN_GOALS : env.MVN_RELEASE_GOALS }"        
                }
            }   
        }       
    }
```